# This DIV is not shown on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, html

I need to do some alert-message (like validations, etc), and I'm doing that with DIV.

This is how I'm doing the validation:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateSearchKeyword();">
        <input class="text_search" id="text_search" name="text_search" type="text" value="pesquisar" onfocus="if (this.value=='pesquisar') this.value = ''" onBlur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'pesquisar'"  />
    </form>
```

and validation function:

```
function validateSearchKeyword()
{
if (document.getElementById('text_search').value==""){creatediv('divAvisoPesquisa','You must supply a value', '355px', '125px');return false;}
}
```

This is the function to create the DIV:

```
function creatediv(id, html, left, top) {

if (document.getElementById(id)) 
    {
        //document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        //fadeIn(id, 300);
    }
    else
    {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.setAttribute("class", "warningDiv"); 
        newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
        newdiv.innerHTML = html;
        newdiv.style.left = left;
        newdiv.style.top = top;
        newdiv.style.display = "none";
        newdiv.onclick=function(e) {
            $(this).fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
        };  
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        $("#"+id).fadeIn(300); 
    }
}
```

The *fadIn* and *fadeOut* functions are from "jquery-1.3.1.min.js"

The CSS...

```
.warningDiv{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:55px;
    padding:15px 25px;
    width:320px;
    z-index:100000;
    display: block;
}
```

So, this is working great for all browsers, except Internet Explorer. Even the validation works (the form is not submitted when it doesn't pass the validation) but the DIV is not shown.
How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific providing the IE version? Or does it occur on every version?

Comment: I'm testing it with IE 7

Comment: I'm just wondering: could the *z-index:100000* be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it.  It seems IE doesn't apply classes the right way if you use:

```
    newdiv.setAttribute("class", "warningDiv");
```

Try using this instead:

```
    newdiv.className="warningDiv";
```

... I just tested, and it shows all the proper CSS properties in IE developer toolbar, which it wasn't doing using the former.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure JQuery's `.fadeIn` doesn't work on IE6.

Try your function without the fade effect or change the effect call to this:

`$("#"+id).fadeIn(300,function() { $(this).show(); });`

Comment: I've tried without the fadeIn and the commented the *display = "none";* but the DIV is not showed. But I installed the IEDeveloperToolbar, and the div is created, but is not visible, and I just don't know why. Thanks

Comment: @Armadillo: Does the element have the proper style according to IE toolbar?  Display:block, position within view, z-index large, etc?

Comment: @Adam Bellaire: No... this is what the style row show: "LEFT: 120px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 250px" |no z-index, block, etc. weird :|

Comment: @Armadillo: It works as expected here. Be sure to have a DOCTYPE set or IE will render your page on quirks mode (I recommend you use XHTML). Also, check the CSS that are applied to that div.

Comment: The DOCTYPE is defined. I'll try to mess around the CSS. Thank you